# Azure Alert for Blob count

Tags: azure, storage, blobstorage, azure-alerts

Is there any way to create an Azure alert which will be triggered if in specific blob container I will reach specific count of files/blobs? For example in blob container named test I will have 100 json files.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Alert in Blob storage, and keep the usage metric as the trigger with a threshold file size, it will be sufflicient i believe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head you could use a Automation Account with a script.

the script would query storage accounts (using a foreach loop) and if the condition is met, an email is sent off to someone?

Another idea, might be able to use Log Analytics and do a Kutso query as the criteria match.

Sorry if this is too light on info